# How to write Latex formulas in HTML tags (such as Div) in Markdown?

Tags: html, latex, markdown

When I write HTML in Typora (a Markdown editor), I want to write Latex formulas in HTML tags (such as Div).

For example, HTML code

[image]

will be displayed as

[image]

This symbol [image] is generated by Latex to generate PDF, and then copied.

Now, I want to directly generate the target row in a way like this:

[image]

That is to write the Latex formula directly in the HTML tag.

How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Known that Typora uses MathJax for real-time rendering.

Comment: No chance to use MathJax or, even better, Katex? :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no (easy) way to directly use `LaTeX` formulas in `HTML` code. If you need to include a lot of LaTeX code into `HTML`, you should try `latex2html`  [here](https://www.latex2html.org/)